# How to select fixed part of rows based on cells selection , Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

in the below code, if I select cell B* or cell C* , It subsequently selects range B*:G* on the same row. please, How to include non-contiguous cell (E) in `Const cFirstRow As String = "B3:C3"` .I tried "B3:C3,E3" but it gives me an error "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const cFirstRow As String = "B3:C3"
    Const sCols As String = "B:G"
    
    Dim crg As Range
    With Range(cFirstRow)
        Set crg = .Resize(Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    
    If Not irg Is Nothing Then
    
        Dim srg As Range, arg As Range, rrg As Range
        For Each arg In irg.Areas
            For Each rrg In arg.Rows
                If srg Is Nothing Then
                    Set srg = Columns(sCols).Rows(rrg.Row)
                Else
                    Set srg = Union(srg, Columns(sCols).Rows(rrg.Row))
                End If
            Next rrg
        Next arg
        
        If Not srg Is Nothing Then
            srg.Select
        End If
    
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: So, would yo like to select the range "B:C,D" of the clicked cell row?

Comment: No ,  Range "B:C,E"

Comment: This is what I meant, but I wrongly wrote... I will prepare a piece of code able to select "B:C,E,G". It should be shorter then your code, I think.

Comment: Range of click is  "B,C,E" and Range of select is B:G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const cFirstRow As String = "B3:C3,E3"
    Const sCols As String = "B:G"
    
    Dim crg As Range
    With Range(cFirstRow)
        Set crg = Intersect(.Areas(1).EntireRow.Resize(rows.Count - .row + 1), .EntireColumn)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    
    If Not irg Is Nothing Then
       'Debug.Print irg.Address: ' Stop
        Dim srg As Range, arg As Range, rrg As Range
        For Each arg In irg.Areas
            For Each rrg In arg.rows
                If srg Is Nothing Then
                    Set srg = Columns(sCols).rows(rrg.row)
                Else
                    Set srg = Union(srg, Columns(sCols).rows(rrg.row))
                End If
            Next rrg
        Next arg
        
        If Not srg Is Nothing Then
            srg.Select
        End If
    
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: after click , the selection is "B:C,E,G" , it suppose to be "B:G"

Comment: addition note: I can not select non-contiguous selection ( previously i was able to ).

Comment: @Waleed_wwm This is simpler... I wrongly understood your question and I thought that you said that in your last comment by mistake. I will adapt the code immediately.

Comment: @Waleed_wwm What do you mean by "not select non-contiguous selection"? Do you intend to select more then a cell? For now, please test the updated code...

Comment: yes , previously i was able to select non-contiguous cells in different rows

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Can you explain **how could you do that**? I mean, technically. Basically, when you make a click, the event is triggered...

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Do you mean, keeping Control and selecting another cell?

Comment: yes , kindly find the original code on this file  https://easyupload.io/9mc4ux

Comment: it works on contiguous select without problem. But on non-contiguous selection I got either of these errors  Run-time error '28': Out of stack space

Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':Method 'Select' of object 'Range' failed

Comment: @Waleed_wwm Then use the updated code. It will only use a discontinuous row for detecting the click...

Comment: @Waleed_wwm: Did you refresh the page (this one)? It works well on discontinuous ranges, too on my computer. Excel 2016 Professional... Sorry, now I can see that it has not been saved. I will post it now. Please, test it now. I kept the initial way of making Union of row areas intersection.

Comment: It works now perfectly on discontinuous row and continuous row . Many great thanks "FaneDuru" for your help & patience .

Comment: Brilliant. The task was to create a reference (`crg`) to the range `B3:Clastrow,E3:Elastrow` (`B3:C1048576,E3:E1048576`).