# Select all Column causes Excel to hang while there is code in event SelectionChange (Intersect)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to do the following:

if I select any cell of `A,D or E on any row (rows)` then subsequently **select Cells B:G on the same row (rows)**.
it works , **But the Problem** If I select any whole column of (A,D or E) then `excel hangs` and not responding.
as always,any help will be appreciated.

```
Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Const cFirstRow As String = "A3,D3,E3"
    Const sCols As String = "B:G"

    Dim crg As Range
    With Range(cFirstRow)
        Set crg = Intersect(.Areas(1).EntireRow.Resize(Rows.Count - .Row + 1), .EntireColumn)
    End With

    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(crg, Target)

    If Not irg Is Nothing Then

        Dim srg As Range, arg As Range, rrg As Range
        For Each arg In irg.Areas
            For Each rrg In arg.Rows
                If srg Is Nothing Then
                    Set srg = Columns(sCols).Rows(rrg.Row)
                Else
                    Set srg = Union(srg, Columns(sCols).Rows(rrg.Row))
                End If
            Next rrg
        Next arg

        If Not srg Is Nothing Then
            srg.Select
        End If
      End If
    
  End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want suggesting that I should remember what you want accomplishing? This code works well for a limited number of selected rows. And (probably) the `Union` has been used in case of discontinuous selections. But I think is very improbable that I would never select a cell in the triggered range, without placing that code line between `EnableEvents = False` followed by `EnableEvents = True`. Please, place a link pointing to the incriminated thread. I anyhow do not remember a code to send 1048576 mails and I supplied such a code for such a purpose. But forgetting is a memory function...

Comment: No, no, I am not upset!  I really believe what I said. I do not remember such a task and asked to see the thread in discussion. It will be easy for you to find it in your profile... Do you need the entire column selection, or want only protecting against selecting it by mistake?

Comment: @FaneDure Thanks, But I do not mention that you created code to send 1048576 mails , I mean the code to select B:G on the same row. anyway that is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058665/how-to-select-fixed-part-of-rows-based-on-cells-selection-excel-vba   on the meantime , I used this temporary solution to avoid Excel hang  **If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A,D:D,E:E")) Is Nothing And Target.Rows.Count > 1000 Then Exit Sub**

Comment: So, you wanly wanted to protect the user against selecting the column by mistake? I can supply a piece of code selecting what the actual code does, but without using `Union`, which takes a lot of time. Anyhow, in that code,  my contribution was only to change a constant from "B3:C3" to "B3:C3,E3"... I didn't even test it. I answer the question which required a solution from this point of view...

Comment: @@FaneDure that is 100/100 correct

Comment: I can show you how to select all that big range instantly, without any iteration and any `Union`, but I do not think it would be wise... Do you want to see such a solution?

Comment: I posted such an answer. In fact, if the uses sees all the column selected he can select again the necessary range... At least for the sake of experimenting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to also select "B:G" in the same row whenever the user selects something in "A, D or E" then there's no need for so many lines of code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TrimmedRange As Range
    Set TrimmedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A,D:D,E:E"))
    If TrimmedRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Union(Target, Intersect(TrimmedRange.EntireRow, Me.Range("B:G"))).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If you want to exclude Rows 1 & 2 from this interaction, you can add a few lines:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TrimmedRange As Range
    Set TrimmedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("3:" & Me.Rows.Count))
    If TrimmedRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set TrimmedRange = Intersect(TrimmedRange, Me.Range("A:A,D:D,E:E"))
    If TrimmedRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Union(Target, Intersect(TrimmedRange.EntireRow, Me.Range("B:G"))).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

An Explanation of the above code:

- `Me.Range("3:" & Me.Rows.Count)` : Create a range of everything from row 3 to the end of the sheet.
- `Intersect(Target, ...` : Compare `Target` to the range, return all cells that are in both ranges. This is effectively trimming the user's selected range by removing anything in the excluded row 1 or 2.
- `Set TrimmedRange = ...` : Save that trimmed range to a variable.
- `Intersect(TrimmedRange, Me.Range("A:A,D:D,E:E"))` : Remove every cell that isnt in columns A,D,E
- `Set TrimmedRange = ...` : Save that double-trimmed range to the variable
- `TrimmedRange.EntireRow` : Extend the remaining cells into full rows.
- `Intersect(TrimmedRange.EntireRow, Me.Range("B:G"))` : Compare those rows to the columns "B:G" and find any overlapping cells. Esentially extends the A,D,E cells into full rows and then takes the "B:G" portion of it.
- `Union(Target, ...` : Re-Add the original user-selected range back into this whole thing
- `Select` : Select the finished range.

Comment: If I select cell on Column **A** it is added to range B:G (It should not) But surprisingly If I select any whole column of (A,D or E) excel not hangs although this big range A3:G1048576 is selected

Comment: Yes, I thought the Target should be added to the finished range. If you dont want it in there, remove the `Union(Target, ` part of the `Select` line.

Comment: Your answer is unique , But it needs to disable events before final select , to avoid loop

Comment: @Waleed78 very true, I will add that in.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try your adapted code in the next way, which does the same, almost instant, but I do not think it is wise to use it...

```
Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Const cFirstRow As String = "A3,D3,E3"
    Const sCols As String = "B3:G3"

    Dim crg As Range, rngBG As Range
    With Range(cFirstRow)
        Set crg = Intersect(.Areas(1).EntireRow.Resize(rows.Count - .row + 1), .EntireColumn)
        Set rngBG = Intersect(Range(sCols).Areas(1).EntireRow.Resize(rows.Count - Range(sCols).row + 1), Range(sCols).EntireColumn)
    End With

    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    
    If Not irg Is Nothing Then
        Dim srg As Range
        Set srg = Intersect(rngBG, irg.EntireRow)

        If Not srg Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False 'without this part, the event will run twice
             srg.Select
             Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
      End If
    
  End Sub
```

Comment: it works , and not cause any hang to excel , kindly why did you mention `not think it is wise to use it`.

Comment: @Waleed78 I tried explaining in a comment... I thought that the user will press a button or something in order to process selection for sending more than a million mails... Then, I said that if the user see such a huge selection it can make a new one.

Comment: your think is true , users will press a button in order to process selection for sending by email , but after your new code , even if any one select by mistake a whole column , no problem.

Comment: @Waleed78 But I think is also wise to test the other answer, too and maybe vote it up, or make it accepted answer. It has been placed before mine and it is complex, with nice explanations. I must close  now my computer. No time to test it, but I will do it tomorrow. At the first sight it should work. After testing I will vote it up...

Answer (score 1):

### Select Row Ranges of a Selection

- This is in the spirit of the posted code. The result is probably the same as in FaneDuru's solution who tackled it a bit differently.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Const cFirstRow As String = "A3,D3,E3"
    Const sCols As String = "B:G"

    Dim crg As Range
    With Range(cFirstRow)
        Set crg = Intersect(.Areas(1).EntireRow _
            .Resize(Rows.Count - .Row + 1), .EntireColumn)
    End With

    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(crg, Target)

    If Not irg Is Nothing Then
        Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(irg.EntireRow, Columns(sCols))
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        srg.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    
End Sub
```